# A way to clean up Nuget packages in the csproj file?

Tags: visual-studio, reference, nuget, nuget-package

As I add and remove references sometimes I don't always "uninstall" a package which appears like a reference.  So it remains "installed" in the Nuget package explorer.  It seem like I could really use something that cleans up the .csproj and the packages.config file -- is there something that does this?

This would be useful for both Visual Studio (VS) 2010 and VS 2012.

Comment: Could you talk a little bit about the sort of clean up you're looking for?

Comment: The problem is that the csproj doesn't have the references but the packages.config does.  The right way to do this is -- if it were added as a package, then simply deleting it from the reference list should offer to uninstall the package -- it doesn't.  Uninstalling the package does remove it from the reference list.  The problem is you can't tell which were packages and which were some other kind of reference.  Some tool to show this would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling a package should be done as an explicit gesture.

If you want to know if a particular reference is part of a package, you can check the Path of the reference. If the hint path is something like "..\Packages\.." , you will know that the reference is part of a package.

Comment: So are you saying if I just delete a reference (that is a Nuget package) and I later want to add it in (because it still says installed in the Nuget Package Manager), I should just add it via the References > Browse to the ./packages/ directory?  Will everything else continue to work?  Will Nuget updates still work?  (I can give this a try I suppose).

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking for a tool to help with cleaning up the packages and at least identify unused Nuget packages for me. For now the manual way to check that a package is used or not is to uninstall the package and compile the project. If everything is still passing that means the package is not used. If things failed you can simply revert the changes in your source control system. You will need to repeat these steps for each package installed in your Visual Studio solution.